# JsonMappingExcept with Objectify on android side

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I am using Objectify for the following schema: Owner, Dog, Toys

```
@Entity
Owner{
    @Id     
    private Long id;     
    private String name;
}

@Entity     
public class Dog {     
    @Id
         private Long id;
         private String name;
    @Load
         @Parent     
    private Ref<Owner> owner;
}

@Entity
     public class Toys {
         @Load     
    @Parent
         private Ref<Dog> dog;
         @Id
         private Long id;
         private String name;
         private String brand;
     }
```

For adding a Toy I use

```
public class DataInput {
         private User user;
         private Toy toy;
}
```

On the android end when I try to add a toy (using the Toy entity and so with Dog and Owner included) I get the error

```
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
 {
   "code": 400,
   "errors": [
     {
       "domain": "global",
       "message": "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: id cannot be zero (through reference chain: com.company.cloud.message.DataInput[\”toy\”]->com.company.cloud.data.Toy[\”dog\”]->com.company.cloud.data.Dog[\”owner\”])”,
       "reason": "badRequest"
     }
   ],
   "message": "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: id cannot be zero (through reference chain: com.company.cloud.message.DataInput[\”toy\”]->com.company.cloud.data.Toy[\”dog\”]->com.company.cloud.data.Dog[\”owner\”])”
 }
```

To be complete, here is my endpoint for adding Toys

```
@ApiMethod(path = "addToy",name = "addToy", httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
     public void addToy(DataInput message) throws UnauthorizedException {
         UserAuthenticator.verifyUser(message.getUser());
         Toy toy = message.getToy();
         ToyDao.persist(toy);
         ToySearchApi.addDocumentToIndex(toy);
     }
```

Comment: The only thing I have never used before is `Ref<>` . So I am thinking it is causing the problem somehow.

Comment: This is really a question about google cloud endpoints and how it serializes data stuctures; you might want to change the title of the question to emphasize that.